# Attachment reminder Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2010

Mozilla Thunderbird has a function to give me a reminder in case I forget to enclose an attachment but use the word "attachment" (or other words, I can define my own list) in the e-mail text.

I've been looking for a similar function in Microsoft Outlook, but can't find it. Only a vague [macro](http://sites.google.com/site/markbird/) from a third party.

Does somebody know about a way to achieve this in Outlook?

Comment: Not natively, no. Not without a vague macro anyway. It's a setting I wanted years ago before I switched to Google Mail.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any standard way. Here is another VBA macro which is more dynamic than the one you've already found by using regexp:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
   Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
   Dim Match, Matches
   Dim mail As MailItem
   
   ' Check if this is a mail
   If Not Item.Class = olMail Then Exit Sub
   
   Set mail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
       
   ' Check if the user forgot the attachment
   Set regEx = New RegExp
   regEx.IgnoreCase = True
   regEx.Global = True
   If mail.Attachments.Count = 0 Then ' no attachment
       Dim s As String
       s = mail.Body
       ' remove previous answers from the convesation (for Outlook 2003)
       If InStr(1, s, "_", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
           s = Mid(s, 1, InStr(1, s, "_", vbTextCompare))
       End If
       ' if the message is not in HTML
       If InStr(1, s, "-Message d'origine-", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
           s = Mid(s, 1, InStr(1, s, "-Message d'origine-", vbTextCompare))
       End If
       
       regEx.Pattern = "(^|^\w+)(attachment|joined|here is|document|linked)^\w+"
       Set Matches = regEx.Execute(s)
       If Matches.Count > 0 Then
           Cancel = MsgBox("VYou may have forgotten to join the attachment. Are you sure you want to send your mail ?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Missing attachment!") = vbNo
       End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Note that you can translate every keyword to your current language.

Here are some documents explaining how to add a macro to Outlook:

- At Super User: [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)
- At Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN): [Adding a VBA Macro to Outlook](https://web.archive.org/web/20151109025145/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/synergist/archive/2007/05/23/adding-a-vba-macro-to-outlook.aspx).

You can also find some [paid solutions](https://web.archive.org/web/20120909034321/http://www.ablebits.com:80/outlook-attachments-missing/index.php).

Comment: Sounds great, thank you very much for your code. Could you amend your answer just a little bit, how to use this code? How do I trigger outlook to use this macro every time I send an email?